# Prevent a duplicate item being added in Localstorage with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am working on a prototype that stores products (like a favourite) into localStorage but I am struggling to check to see if an item already exists in localStorage so its not added again.

Where would the best place be to check for a duplicate entry and handle it gracefully?

My sample controller is below:

```
function dCtrl($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.d = [
        {id:'1',d_name:'Product 1',colour:'Blue'},
        {id:'2',d_name:'Product 2',colour:'Red'},
        {id:'3',d_name:'Product 3',colour:'Cream'},
        {id:'4',d_name:'Product 4',colour:'White'},
        {id:'5',d_name:'Product 5',colour:'Green'},
        {id:'6',d_name:'Product 6',colour:'Black'},
        {id:'7',d_name:'Product 7',colour:'Purple'},
        {id:'8',d_name:'Product 8',colour:'Grey'},
        {id:'9',d_name:'Product 9',colour:'Yellow'},
        {id:'10',d_name:'Product 10',colour:'Indigo'}
    ];

  $scope.getDetails = function (id, favDresses) {

      //get the object of the item clicked
      single_object = $filter('filter')($scope.d, {id:id})[0];
      // If you want to see the result, check console.log
      console.log(single_object); 
      console.log('ID:' + id + ' - save this object to localStorage');

      //set localstorage var
      var storage = localStorage.getItem('newfavdresses');

      //check to see if the localStorage array is empty (not null)
      if(storage != null) {

        //if it isnt, parse the string
        favDresses = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newfavdresses'));
        //push into the array
        favDresses.push(single_object);
        //set the item in localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("newfavdresses",JSON.stringify(favDresses));

      } else {

        //if the array is null, create it
        var favDresses = [];
        //and push the item into it
        favDresses.push(single_object);
        //set the item in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("newfavdresses",JSON.stringify(favDresses));

      }

  }

  $scope.clearStorage = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    alert('Local Storage Cleared');
  }

//get localStorage items  
var dresses = localStorage.getItem("newfavdresses");
dresses = JSON.parse(dresses);
console.log(dresses);

}
```

jsFiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dwhiteside86/Lt7aP/2261/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is work with live javascript array stored in service.

You would load this array from localStorage when service initializes or set to empty array if nothing in storage.

Then whenever you update the stored array you always store back the whole thing into localStorage so that the stored version is always a string replica of the live one.

This way you only use `getItem()` once and then have a simple service method `storeLocal()` that you call each time you modify array or object in array.

Another thing you might look at is [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) that does all of the above for you

Comment: I will look at both of these options!

Comment: This approach is great for prototyping but I just wonder how large can a single string be and if there are any differences under the hood compared to using many key/value pair. Anyway, I'll have to run my tests. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage, I believe it will solve all your issues. This library will bind your scope property to local storage so You'll dont care about how it stores.

Comment: I'll check this out when I get to my desk!